# Pandas bin column and find count from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I rarely touch Pandas or data analysis in general, so is probably a trivial solution.

I have a 2 column dataset as shown:

[image]

I want to group the ROI column into a set number of bins (e.g. 5) and then count how many HITS (1's or 0s) go into each bin.

```
raw_df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')

roi_ds = raw_df['ROI']

binned_rois = pd.cut(roi_ds , bins=5)
```

How can I link each bin to how many HIT's there are in the HIT column?

Expected example output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) if need 2 new columns for `0` and `1` values:

```
raw_df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')

df1 = pd.crosstab(pd.cut(raw_df['ROI'], bins=5), raw_df['ROI'])
```

Or if need 3 columns:

```
df2 = df.groupby([pd.cut(raw_df['ROI'], bins=5), 'HIT']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```